Smart TV Device Not Showing Pairing Code iOS
 self.connectedDevice = obj
 self.connectedDevice?.delegate = self
 self.connectedDevice?.setPairingType(DeviceServicePairingTypeMixed)
 self.connectedDevice?.connect()

Pairing Code Screen Not Shown on Connectable Device
How to show pairing code screen to smart TV connectable device? Connect SDK

Which SDK are you using?  What is connectedDevice?

For showing pairing code screen on smart tv you can use socket in swift instead of using connectSDK. I have implement a full code for it to control smart tv devices with pairing code functionality.

Thank You for reply, Connect SDK not pairing code so another lib provide so we can successfully connected. Did you have idea about Casting Local Gallery video to Smart TV?

Is there any other options for casting video and images iOS to Smart Android TV?

Use caster for ios library: Here is github link https://github.com/davidholmesnyc/Caster-for-iOS-
